# How to redirect an iOS user from Chrome to Safari?

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm building an iPhone webapp using HTML5. To help the webapp resemble a native app, users need to add it to their homescreen. But for this to work, they have to be on Safari. Other mobile browsers, such as Chrome, cannot add bookmarks to the homescreen.

If a user accesses my webapp using the Chrome browser, how can I redirect him/her to Safari?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official documentation that states how to send URL request from native app to mobileSafari as of iOS 6.1, but there a few hacks you could use for example JavaScript callbacks. it not 100% prefect and take a bit of effect from the client side. follow this guide [here](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/chrome-for-ios-send-a-webpage-back-to-safari-via-bookmarklet/).

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for something more stable. Is there a way to add a bookmark to the homescreen directly via Chrome?

Comment: sorry that also not possible from chrome browser